# Launching an EC2 Fleet across multiple subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to launch an [EC2 Fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-fleet.html) of ~2000 instances across several subnets, each subnet in a different AZ to minimize fate sharing between the instances. We are creating the fleet with a list of subnets in the override config, but it is picking a single subnet from that list and attempting to launch all the instances in that subnet.

How can I configure the fleet so that it can spread the instances it launches across the subnets provided?

Using the [AWS Node.js SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#createFleet-property), here's the code I'm attempting to use for launching the fleet:

```js
/**
 * Launch an EC2 fleet.
 *
 * @param {object} params Params.
 * @param {number} params.count Number of instances to launch.
 * @param {string} params.launchTemplateName Name of template to launch.
 * @param {string} params.launchTemplateVersion Version of template to launch.
 * @param {string[]} params.subnetIds Array of subnets to launch the instances on.
 * @returns {Promise<PromiseResult<EC2.CreateFleetResult, AWSError>>}
 */
function launchFleet({ count, launchTemplateName, launchTemplateVersion, subnetIds }) {
  const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
  const subnetId = subnetIds.join(',');
  return ec2
    .createFleet({
      TargetCapacitySpecification: {
        TotalTargetCapacity: count,
        OnDemandTargetCapacity: count,
        SpotTargetCapacity: 0,
        DefaultTargetCapacityType: 'on-demand',
      },
      LaunchTemplateConfigs: [
        {
          LaunchTemplateSpecification: {
            LaunchTemplateName: launchTemplateName,
            Version: launchTemplateVersion,
          },
          Overrides: [
            {
              SubnetId: subnetId,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      ExcessCapacityTerminationPolicy: 'no-termination',
      ReplaceUnhealthyInstances: false,
      Type: 'maintain',
    })
    .promise();
}
```

Comment: Is it always choosing the first value n the comma-separated list? If you use `DescribeFleets()` after it is launched, what is it showing for the `Overrides.SubnetId` value?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, it launches on any of the given subnets; not just the first one. Overrides.SubnetId is showing the same comma separated list I passed into the createFleet().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use Auto Scaling groups instead of EC2 Fleet, since balancing instances across AZs is a key requirement. Using [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#createAutoScalingGroup-property) this should be a straightforward change.

The other thing I'd suggest, is to use Spot instances instead of On-Demand or mix of both to optimize the cost. This is possible through the **MixedInstancesPolicy** property, and as a best practice you can use multiple instance types and **capacity-optimized** as *SpotAllocationStrategy* to allow ASG to pick the capacity from the most available instance pools.

Also ASG will be able to keep number of instance at the desired capacity by replacing any interrupted Spot instances.

Comment: Spot instances don't work well for our use case. Each instance is stateful and is not easily replaced. Given the precious-ness of our individual instances, I was worried about ASG's terminating or scaling them in. But reading the docs, it looks like I can set termination protection on the ASG. I'll give it a try!